# Error: (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for ActivatedRoute: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to inject ActivatedRoute component into my component to access the ID of the object I'm editing (or to find out, there's no ID param, new object is created).

I've created only the template for the component, and when I load start page (not event the page with the component I want to use) I get the following error:

> Error: (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for ActivatedRoute: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?).

This is my code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-edit',
    templateUrl: './templates/my-edit.htm',
    providers: [ActivatedRoute]
})

export class MyEditComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private route : ActivatedRoute){
        console.log(route.params)
    }

    ngOnInit() : void {
    }

}
```

It's based on the code from example from AngularJS site (Heroes), and I really don't get where's the problem here... Can't I import ActivatedRoute into Component, or I need something extra to be able to import it?

My routing configuration is:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

where `routes` are the collection of routes, just like in angular example, and `AppRoutingModule` is imported in app.module.

Comment: Did you provide `Router.forRoot()` at the `AppModule`?

Comment: And don't add the `ActivatedRoute` to the `@Component.providers`

Comment: @peeskillet it seems to be that, I've got it wrong, I thought .providers are necessary to inject params into constructor

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Remove `providers: [ActivatedRoute]` from `@Component()` there is no need for that. `RouterModule.forRoot()` already provides everything that is required.

Answer (score 2):

To extend @günter-zöchbauer's answer. Make sure that you added `RouterModule` to property `exports` of `@NgModule`. Directives/pipes/modules specified in `exports` will be

> used within the template of **any component that is part of an Angular
>   module** that imports this Angular module.

i.e. in all child components of the module.