# Angular 2 : Can't resolve all parameters for ActivatedRoute

Tags: angular

I have add the provider for activedroute and now it give this error, i want to get query string parameter, for example : `http://localhost:4200/?user=hello`

I want get value of user, this is my code :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';



@Component({
selector: 'app-login',
templateUrl: './login.html'
})

export class LoginBancaComponent implements OnInit  {

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}



ngOnInit() {
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
    let str= params['user'];
    console.log(str);
  });
 }


}
```

But on console page there is this error:

> Can't resolve all parameters for ActivatedRoute: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?).

I have import everything in module :

```
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';
...
imports: [
BrowserModule,
CommonModule, RouterModule,
],
providers: [ActivatedRoute],
...
```

Why there is this error ?

Comment: what is the exact error could you  print here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for ActivatedRoute: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40509325/error-systemjs-cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-activatedroute)

Comment: Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ActivatedRoute: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?).
    at syntaxError (vendor.bundle.js:21312)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (vendor.bundle.js:35399)

Comment: Robby Cornelissen i have just read that question but I don't know how you use RouterModule.forRoot()

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to provide `ActivatedRoute` yourself, it is already provided in the `RouterModule`. You get this error, because `ActivatedRoute` has probably other dependencies which you do not provide. Just remove it from your `providers` array in your module.

Comment: Done, but now it works but it print on console undefined

Comment: Is this your root module or a feature module?

Comment: So does it solve your error? The `undefined` may be because of your `let str= params['user'];` line. You may not have passed a `user` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
// 1. inject activatedRoute with name 'route'
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){ }

ngOnInit() {
    // 2. use right name 'route' as injected above
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        let str = params['user'];
        console.log(str);
    });
}
```