# Angular 4 - Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for ActivatedRoute: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, router, testbed

I have referred the following link to get the answers, but I couldn't find any working solution for my scenario. 
[Error: (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for ActivatedRoute: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40509325/error-systemjs-cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-activatedroute)

Therefore, I have been trying to remove the Activated Route from the providers and still the test bed is not passing. It shows

> Error: No provider for ActivatedRoute!

So here is my code, I want to run my test bed in the angular application which is using **Jasmine.**

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

describe('SomeComponent', () => {
  let component: SomeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SomeComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({ 
      imports: [ RouterModule, RouterTestingModule ],
      declarations: [ SomeComponent ],
      providers: [ ActivatedRoute ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Error getting

[image]

Comment: `ActivatedRoute` is one of the providers already defined by the `RouterModule`, you shouldn't include it again. Also note that there is a `RouterTestingModule` that may be more appropriate for your needs.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You want to inject a fake ActivatedRoute to your component, since you create it yourself in the test, and the router thus doesn't create it for you and inject an ActivatedRoute. So you can use something like this:

```
describe('SomeComponent', () => {

  const fakeActivatedRoute = {
    snapshot: { data: { ... } }
  } as ActivatedRoute;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({ 
      imports: [ RouterTestingModule ],
      declarations: [ SomeComponent ],
      providers: [ {provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: fakeActivatedRoute} ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
});
```

Comment: Thing is, how do you populate the snapshot object so it works?

Comment: Why do I HAVE to fake it? Is there any example on the internet where I actually simulate reading URLs?

Comment: This answer brought me the solution: Still in Angular 14: I added to the imports RouterTestingModule
(there was no need to add {provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: fakeActivatedRoute})

Answer (score 17):

Here's a solution for angular 7

```
{
    provide: ActivatedRoute,
    useValue: {
        snapshot: {
            paramMap: {
                get(): string {
                    return '123';
                },
            },
        },
    },
},
```

Answer (score 6):

```js
{
  provide: ActivatedRoute,
  useValue: {
    snapshot: {
      queryParamMap: {
        get(): number {
          return 6;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I resolved this just by Adding `RouterTestingModule` to **imports** instead of adding `ActivatedRoute` to **Providers**

Answer (score 1):

Remove ActivatedRoute, this don't require testing